Show that $\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \sup_n \int_{\{|f_n|>K|\}}|f_n|d\mu=0$
I am trying to solve the following problem: Let $f_n \in \mathcal{L}_2(S, \Sigma, \mu)$. Show that if
$$\sup_n \int f_n^2 d\mu < \infty$$
then $$\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \sup_n \int_{\{|f_n|>K|\}}|f_n|d\mu=0.$$
We define $\mathcal{L}_2(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ := $\{ f_n \ \text{is measurable}, ||f_n||_2 < \infty\}$. By definition $||f_n||_2=\left(\int |f_n|^2 d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. I have only gotten thus far that $$\sup_n \int f_n^2 d\mu = \int |f_n|^2 d\mu < \infty.$$ What would be the next steps to be able to define the limit over the set $(|f_n|>K)$ and observe that it equals to 0?

We have for $K>0$
$$
\int_{|f_n|\geq K} |f_n|\,d\mu = \int_{|f_n|\geq K} \frac{K}{K}|f_n|\,d\mu\leq \frac{1}{K}\int_{|f_n|\geq K} |f_n|^2\,d\mu \leq \frac{\sup_n \int|f_n|^2\,d\mu}{K}
$$
which yields the asserted.
Remark: The property you would like to show is called uniform integrability and the statement would be also true if you replace 2 by $1+\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon>0$.

Thank you! Where does the assumption of $\sup_n \int f_n^2 d\mu < \infty$ comes to use? Also does assuming $K>0$ can be used without limiting generality?

As you send $K$ to $+\infty$, $K=0$ does not play any role so we can rule it out. The boundedness of the $\sup$ is needed to conclude that the RHS tends to 0 as $K\to\infty$.

Thank you once again! I started questioning the last inequality. The assumption is given for $\sup_n \int f_n^2 d\mu$ but does it apply for $\sup_n \int |f_n|^2 d\mu$ as well?

It holds for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $x^2=|x|^2$.
